# LAPTOP BATTERY ideapad lenovo

Tags: windows, lenovo-laptop, battery-life

Design capacity
629.75 Wh
Full charge capacity
23.4 Wh
is my battery life is poor , do i need to replace it?
is there any way of calculating life of battery?

Answer (score 1):

> Design capacity 629.75 Wh

That's impossible. Modern laptops have batteries between 42 Wh and < 100 Wh. Up to 100 Wh is allowed on a plane. I'm assuming it's a typo and you meant 62.75 Wh. (unless you have a car battery attached to that laptop)

> Full charge capacity 23.4 Wh

That's 37% of design capacity. This battery is dead.

> do i need to replace it?

If battery life is insufficient or the laptop is not booting, then yes. Otherwise no.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, I think you need to decide whether it's software or battery hardware issue.

For Lenovo, it usually provides some software, such as power management, downloaded and installed on the official website and then checked the battery.

Also you could reinstall your video card driver from the manufacturer's official website. There are some battery power display issues related to the integrated graphics card.